# GCMIntent service occasionally stops receiving messages

Tags: android, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented the full functionality of GCM and everything works perfectly. When I start the app I get the `regId` and everything looks good. But every now and then my GCMIntent service seems to stop receiving incoming messages. I want to know if there is something wrong with the GCM service and is there any way to check whether the notification has been sent to the device or not. Below is my client side code to register and then my GCMIntent service.

```
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
        if(GCMRegistrar.isRegistered(this))
        {
            final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);//app_preferences.getString(Constants.KEY_DEVICE_TOKEN, "");;
            if(!regId.equals(""))
            {
                mRegIds= regId;
                //sendIdToServer(regId);
                Log.i("DEVICE TOKEN", regId);
                is_gcm_registered = true;
            } 
        }

        else
        {
            GCMRegistrar.register(this, Constants.SENDER_ID);
            is_gcm_registered = false;
        }
```

GCM INTENT SERVICE:

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.e("GOT INCOMING MESSAGE","HI");
    // My implementation
}
```

Problem is sometimes it works immediately and sometimes it can take up to 1 to 2 minutes to receive a notification. Is this normal?

EDIT:
I was reading up on GCM Throttling 
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#throttling
and it says that the application runs out of tokens if messages are sent to the same device in bulk. So GCM is not the best way to implement an Instant Messaging application?

Comment: in which device you check this?

Comment: i have an htc evo 3d. and htc wildfire s.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the delay is normal - especially when the phone has gone to sleep for a few minutes. You'll notice that if you're actively using the phone, messages tend to arrive instantaneously.

Don't worry too much - the message will arrive eventually.

Comment: actually I am relying on GCM for instant message application. So i have to receive notifications immediately else its a lost cause. And this is happening quite often. is urban airship a better option or is it just a wrapper on GCM.